# how to run two selenium java files on after the other continuously when they dont have any relation in between them

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, execution

I have a web application for which I have done automation tests in Selenium using TESTNG on admin module and user module. Now I need to run the java files continuously one after the other(1st admin then the user module). No methods are common between them. I just want to run the user module java file as soon as the admin module has finished running.

Comment: You should tell us more. How are implemented your selenium tests? As JUnit tests?

Comment: @LaurentG I have implemented Selenium tests using TestNG...

Comment: Create a build relationship between them. There are a few ways to do this

Comment: If you have batch execution, I think you can create a shell calling the modules one after the other with specified configurations

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependsOn attribute of TestNG if one test is dependent on pass/fail of previous one OR you can use groups attribute. Refer TestNG site, they have good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using Testing framework is preferable, still if you are not interested, you can create a standalone  class, from the main method, call your test class's main method one by one as per your requirement. Simple :)