# How to run two java files one by one- Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

- Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**. I have a project called**Test**.
- In that Project i have many Java Programs such as **Login.java**, **Testing1.java** etc.,.
- The scenario is 1st the **Login.java** need to run once it completed then next file start to run i.e **Testing1.java**. 
  -Is there any possible to run like this in Eclipse. I'm using FF 26.0 for execution. ** TestNG** frame work.

[image]

Comment: Create test suite and execute all test classes in that suite in the specified order.

Comment: Use package options for that

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369629/how-to-run-two-selenium-java-files-on-after-the-other-continuously-when-they-don

Comment: How to create a test suite.. Any sample example for the two files

Comment: possible duplicate of [What installable component provides 'launch groups' in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003337/what-installable-component-provides-launch-groups-in-eclipse)

Comment: Please give soltion how to create a test suite

Comment: What's wrong with a single `main` to run each of your components one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) make a new file src/testng.xml 
(or edit if already exist)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.LoginOneReports"/>
        <class name="test.OEPR_DefaultTab"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

2) Eclipse:
Run \ Run Configurations... 
'Test' tab, 'Suite' radiobutton, Browse. Choose your testng.xml file.
Click Run.

Hope it would help ;)